# Liferay instance setting

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.2

I have one issue in updating the instance settings.

The error comes like below when I am updating an instance setting in Liferay. It is an error like is null pointer exception please suggest any solution.

```
2020-03-26 06:51:13.317 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][PortletServlet:119] javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.ModelListenerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.ModelListenerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.BaseMVCActionCommand.processAction(BaseMVCActionCommand.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:378)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:260)
        at com.liferay.configuration.admin.web.internal.portlet.InstanceSettingsPortlet.processAction(InstanceSettingsPortlet.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:77)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:115)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:589)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:632)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:304)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.processAction(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:213)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:521)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$processAction$0(PortletContainerImpl.java:150)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:425)
        at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.processAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:143)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:93)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.processAction(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:76)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.processAction(PortletContainerUtil.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:346)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:170)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:415)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:155)
        at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:215)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:357)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:182)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:409)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:368)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

Liferay version 7.2

Comment: If custom code is involved (ModelListener) sounds like it: Please post it, and include a root cause, if available in the stacktrace. If no custom code is involved, this is offtopic for stackoverflow ([help/on-topic]).

Comment: i.e. currently, I see 3 reasons to close this question: 1) not programming related (as there's no code), 2) asking for debugging help (but no code, and no detailed steps to reproduce), 3) duplicate of "What is a NullpointerException?". Please edit your question to eliminate these 3, otherwise you risk it to be closed

Comment: And last comment: Please observe https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505 and act accordingly